# Поместить список файлов в архив

Tags: python, python-3.x

как список файлов в папке поместить в архив?, не саму папку с содержимым, а именно содержимое засунуть в архив

```
DIRECTORY = f'{g}'
    result = os.listdir(DIRECTORY)

    patoolib.create_archive(f"{file_name_without_extension}.rar", (f"{g}/{result}",))
```

выдаёт ошибку

> patoolib.util.PatoolError: file `10-lines/['белый цвет', 'красный цвет', 'синий цвет']' was not found

Comment: Покажите свой код и объясните что у вас не получается

Comment: Смотрите, приложил код здесь, не могу список файлов засунуть в архив, не могу понять почему не получается

Comment: если только {g} то это папка архивируется, а мне это не нужно, мне нужно перенести в архив содержимое этой папки

Comment: ['белый цвет', 'красный цвет', 'синий цвет']
это список чего?

Comment: папок с файлами

Comment: os.listdir() получает список файлов по указанному пути
для архивации файлов в этих папках, нужно применить os.listdir() для каждой из папок соответственно

Comment: А эта библиотека или что patoolib

Comment: да, это библиотека

Comment: где вы её взяли просто вот так она не устанавливается pip install patoolib

Comment: это отрывок кода, сам код 200 строк+, у меня не работает именно тут, я могу прислать весь код

Comment: к сожалению код прислать не смогу, не вставляет сюда

Comment: Попробуйте другой архиватор pip install rarfile https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-rarfile

Comment: сам факт того, что я не могу заархивировать файлы из папки в rar архив, если, кто знает как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: мне нужно постараться через patool, поскольку он не требует winrar.exe, чтобы архивировать

Comment: Да этот может тоже не требует

Comment: Ну или скачайте winrar в чём проблема

Comment: Как мы можем вам помочь если не знаем что за библиотеку вы используете

Comment: не получится с winrar, поскольку этот код будет конвертироваться в exe файл и будет скриптом

Comment: А не проще pyinstaller?

Comment: Если честно не чего не понятно что вы там хотите и куда затолкать

Comment: Это такой exe-скрипт?)

Answer (score 0):

предварительно нужно установить библиотеку `pip install zipfile`

```py
import zipfile
import os
dir = os.listdir('')
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w')
for file in dir:
   archive.write(file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
archive.close()
```

Comment: нет, меня волнует конкретно с rar с зип всё элементарно